# Is Roboteq motor driver compatible with Arduino?

Tags: arduino-mega, motor

I'm planning use Roboteq motor driver for 24V brushed DC motor but I can't be sure that it's true or wrong. You know, Roboteq controller is too expensive and I don't want to spend money in vain. Have you any experience this controller? Are they compatible with Arduino?

http://www.roboteq.com/index.php/roboteq-products-and-services/brushed-dc-motor-controllers/mdc2230-detail  Roboteq Controller Link

I also think, Pololu RoboClaw driver. https://www.pololu.com/product/1499 I don't know is it enough for wheelchair. Because, I already have used Pololu VNH5019 and it is not enough. (synchronicity and noise problems etc.)

If you have any ideas, I will be glad. Thank you.

Comment: and i dont know this group suitable for this subject. If i wrong, correct me please.

Comment: This site is suitable for questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not directly supported. But the device description lists RS232 port that can be interfaced with an Arduino using a TTL to RS232 converter. The description also mentions "several Analog, Pulse and Digital I/Os which can be remapped as command or feedback inputs, limit switches, or many other functions" so it is totally possible to control the controller with an Arduino, but depending on the method you choose it may require some effort.